# Is the sum of reciprocals of primes between $n$ and $n!$ smaller than $1$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $\sigma(n) = \displaystyle\sum_{\substack{p\nmid n,\,\ p\leq n \\ p\text{ prime}}}\frac{1}{p}$. Is $\sigma(n!) < 1$ for $n$ sufficiently large?

I'm trying to tackle the problem this way:

Let $q$ be the smallest prime that doesn't divide $n$. Is $\sigma(qn) < \sigma(n)$?

So far I haven't been able to make any meaningful progress.

Comment: Do you know [Mertens' theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems), in particular the second?

Comment: @TravisJ fixed it.

Comment: @DanielFischer so $\sigma(n!)$ is about $\ln\ln n! - \ln\ln n$?

Comment: Right. Now use Stirling's formula to see how $\sigma(n!)$ behaves.

Comment: @DanielFischer well, looks like the answer to my question is no. That's too bad. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll award you the points and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Mertens' second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems), we have

$$\sigma(n!) = \sum_{n < p \leqslant n!} \frac{1}{p} = \ln \ln n! - \ln \ln n + \varepsilon_n$$

with $\varepsilon_n \to 0$. Using Stirling's formula

$$\ln n! = \bigl(n + \tfrac{1}{2}\bigr) \ln n - n + \ln \sqrt{2\pi} + O(1/n),$$

we then obtain

$$\ln \ln n! = \ln n + o(\ln n),$$

whence

$$\sigma(n!) \sim \ln n.$$

Answer (score 1):

So $\sigma(n!)$ is the sum of the reciprocals of the primes greater than $n$ and less than $n!$.  (BTW, this conflicts with the [usual use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) of the symbol $\sigma$ in number theory, but never mind...)

By the Prime Number Theorem, the density of primes around $m$ is asymptotically $1/\log m$, so we should have
$$\sum_{p < m} \dfrac{1}{p} \approx \int_2^m \dfrac{dx}{x\log x} \approx \ln \ln m $$
Now $\ln \ln n! \approx \ln(n \ln n) \approx \ln n$, so 
$\sigma(n!) \approx \ln n - \ln \ln n \approx \ln n$.  And of course this is greater than $1$ for large $n$.